# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on a UITableView with ARC?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I am building a simple app with a custom bar tab which loads the content of the `ViewController` from a `UITableView` located in another `ViewController`.

However, every time I try to scroll on the tableview, I get an `exc_bad_access` error. I enabled `NSzombies` and guard malloc to get more info on the issue.

In the console I get:

```
"message sent to deallocated instance 0x19182f20"
```

and after profiling I get:

```
#   Address             Category                    Event Type  RefCt     Timestamp Size    Responsible Library   Responsible Caller
56  0x19182f20          FirstTabBarViewController   Zombie      -1        00:16.613.309 0   UIKit                 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewWillBeginDragging]
```

Here is a bit of the code of the ViewController in which the error occurs:
.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DataController.h"

@interface FirstTabBarViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  {
    IBOutlet UITableView* tabBarTable;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabBarTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DataController *messageDataController;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "FirstTabBarViewController.h"
#import "DataController.h"

@interface FirstTabBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstTabBarViewController
@synthesize tabBarTable=_tabBarTable;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.messageDataController=[[DataController alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.messageDataController countOfList];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    };

    NSString *expenseAtIndex = [self.messageDataController
                                   objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:expenseAtIndex];
    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

@end
```

This FirstTabBarViewController is loaded in the MainViewController with the following custom segue:

```
#import "customTabBarSegue.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation customTabBarSegue

-(void) perform {
    MainViewController *src= (MainViewController *) [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst=(UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    for (UIView *view in src.placeholderView.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    src.currentViewController =dst;
    [src.placeholderView addSubview:dst.view];



}
@end
```

The Datacontroller class is just a simple NSMutableArray containing strings.

I am using ARC so I don't understand where the memory management error comes from. Does anybody have a clue?

Any help much appreciated ;) 
 Thanks!!

Comment: "Does anybody have a clue?" - without any code? No.

Comment: sorry, I just added some code - thanks for your help

Comment: The problem seems to be at a higher lever than the code you're showing us : you're accessing tableView from a viewController from - you say - AN OTHER viewController. 

I'm guessing you're using a UITabBarController or any other kind of container, and trying to access `FirstTabBarViewController` from 
If so, please : give us the real code

Comment: yes, I have a viewcontroller which serves as a custom tab bar controller. From this viewcontroller i load a tableview located in another viewcontroller with a custom segue

Comment: Then the EXC_BAD_ACCESS really is IN this custom tab bar controller code, which is trying to access a deallocated `FirstTabBarViewController`

Comment: ok, is there anyway I can retain the variables from the FirstTabBarViewController in the custom tab bar controller after the tableview is loaded? 
btw, if it is of any help, the project can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d90prbw5ekmu7d5/uLUtkFEK0J

Comment: There's actually no code in the MainViewController, I set it up in the storyboard and linked it to the FirstViewControler with a custom segue.
I edited my question with the code of the segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Thank you for the code sample...

See [UIStoryboardSegue documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboardSegue/perform), when you implement `perform` in your `customTabBarSegue`, you're responsible for setting, in the end, the correct **relationship** between your 2 viewControllers.
You have 2 possibilities:

- setting dst as a modal child (then src is `presentingViewController` of dst), adding this code at the end of `perform`: `[src presentViewController:dst animated:NO completion:nil];`
- setting dst as a child viewController of src - adding this code : `[src addChildViewController:dst];`
  at the end of `perform`, but then, you have to remove it somewhere, or remove other childs in the same method....

Here's an implementation

```
@implementation customTabBarSegue

-(void) perform {
    MainViewController *src= (MainViewController *) [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst=(UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    for (UIView *view in src.placeholderView.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    src.currentViewController =dst;
    [src.placeholderView addSubview:dst.view];

    // this container only show 1 viewController at a time, so we can remove previous ones
    for (UIViewController *vc in src.childViewControllers) {
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [vc removeFromParentViewController];
    }
    //then add the new View controller as child
    [src addChildViewController:dst];

}
@end
```

Anyway, you should definitively look more into UIViewController containment...

Comment: I'll deep dive into the UIViewController containment. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: edit with proper removal of children before adding the new one